# SearchCommand in Toolbar no longer showing correctly

Tags: codenameone

I noticed that after an update of CN1 some time ago, the Search doesn't display correctly in the toolbar anymore.

When you click the search icon, the toolbar will change and the icons will show, but the textfield for entering the search text (and which normally shows a hint) doesn't show up even if you start to type. It is only shown when you provoke a refresh of the screen, e.g. click in the search field or on the form.

```
Form hi18 = new Form("FormTitle");
hi18.setLayout(BoxLayout.y());
Container cont18 = hi18.getContentPane();
hi18.getToolbar().addSearchCommand((e) -> {
    String text = (String) e.getSource();
    for (Component c : hi18.getContentPane()) {
        c.setHidden(c instanceof Label && ((Label) c).getText().indexOf(text) < 0);
    }
    hi18.getComponentForm().animateLayout(150);
});
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Label l = new Label("Label " + i);
    cont18.add(l);
}
hi18.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine for me considering you created a title with no text in it for the test case so it might be shrinking on you. I suggest adding text to the title and making sure your styling doesn't impact this too much. I would also suggest adding screenshots when discussing something that doesn't look right so we're all on the same page.

These were generated with your code on the current trunk:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember to include screenshots. However, it seems you observe the same problem as I mentioned: immediately after pressing the search button, you don't see the Search hint ("<search icon>Search") where you should type the search text. I also guess that if you start typing text immediately after the first press of the Search icon (on the Simulator), you don't see the typed text until you click somewhere (either in the form or where the search textarea is supposed to be)?

Comment: The hint disappears in native editing mode by default. You can use a theme constant to make it show when using native editing too: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html#_theme_constants

Comment: The comment is about the Simulator, and it is in my view clearly a regression compared to earlier (correct) behavior. Did you compare to earlier versions of CN1? (NB. In the example code, adding a Form title changes nothing).

Comment: I clicked elsewhere on the form and it shows the hint when I don't edit. I replaced the screenshot of the iOS version with that. There was no change to Toolbar/SearchBar related to this (I went over the git sources). I'm guessing text field fixed the editing behavior to start immediately so the hint isn't visible initially but that's a vague guess.

Comment: I've updated the code sample to show more directly what happens. What I see: click the search icon: the hint text isn’t shown (but it should be, and it was previously), then immediately start typing and the typed text isn’t shown (but the list is filtered as expected). Click somewhere (on form or search text field) and the typed search text is now suddenly shown. You may very well be right that the issue is linked to changes in TextField, but I haven’t tried to debug as this seems to be a regression in CN1.

Comment: This seems related to a regression in the text field. Does it only happen in the simulator or does it happen on the device too? Can you file an issue with this description here https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/ and include that information?

Comment: Yes, it is also the case on an iPhoneXr (build made a couple of weeks ago). Yes, I’ll file an issue, thanks for your feedback. As a side note, debugging this kind of issues seem to be more complicated with the ‘asynchronous screen refresh’ (not sure if that’s the right words to describe it) - maybe a small blog post this topic could be worthwhile?